# Finding UI elements of all activities in an app (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to create an app where I find all its activities and then I find all the UI elements in all of its activities so I can find how many buttons are used etc.. I have found how to find all activities but couldn't find anywhere how to get all the elements.. Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    }    


    public void findActivities(View view) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        ActivityInfo[] appActivities = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;

    }
}
```

Comment: Other than maybe a learning project, why do you want that?  What purpose would it serve?  But anyway, not possible.  Because there's no static mapping of Activities->views.  You can't even walk the xml files, because some could be used multiple times, some could be unused, and some Activities could create their views at runtime without xml.  There's no real way to do this.